# How does the 'as' reserved word work in Django Template Language?

Tags: django, django-templates

I cannot find an explanation of the 'as' reserved word in DTL.

get_cart is inside carton_tags:

`{% load carton_tags %}
{% get_cart as cart  %}`

I have reviewed the documentation for Django Template language and have read the code for DTL reserved/keyword/'tags' without success.

Part of my problem is probably trying to find the string 'as', ' as', 'as ', or ' as ' in these docs.

docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#templates

source: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaulttags.py

code is from here: https://github.com/lazybird/django-carton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Assignment tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags) allow you to store the result of a template tag in a variable. The [`get_cart`](https://github.com/lazybird/django-carton/blob/f59fd9448dda0738569f0630606e0df6ad8bd681/carton/templatetags/carton_tags.py#L25) tag that you linked to is an assignment tag.

After running

```
{% get_cart as cart  %}
```

You can then access the result of the `get_cart` tag in the `{{ cart }}` variable.

Note that not all Django template tags support the `as` keyword. Assignment tags are deprecated, in Django 1.9+ you can use the as keyword with [simple tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason the assignment tag doesn't seem to preserve itself between template blocks?

Comment: That's by design. See the note headed 'Variable scope in context' in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#setting-a-variable-in-the-context).